# How to set a property of an entity while creating an instance of it

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

Here is my code.

```
     modelBuilder.Entity<ProductType>()
           .HasRequired(x => x.Product)
           .WithMany(x => x.ProductTypes)
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId);
```

I want to set a property of ProductType if Product's IsDiscount property is true.

Comment: (That's not a class, but there was a bunch of unnecessary code that I did remove.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this

```
Product product = new Product 
{
    Name = "test",
    Price = 34.5,
    ....
}
```

Comment: Why are you using it then? It is mainly used for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I create surrogate classes and I use them for manuplating property values.